# Update unique compound indexes on an existing data set

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, compound-index

Problem:

I'm trying to update a unique compound index on an existing data set and Mongo isn't updating the index.

Background:

In the database for our web app we have a unique compound index using a user's clubID and email. This means emails must be unique in regards to a user's clubID.

I'm in the process of updating this index to allow users to share emails. We added a new property on the user model called 'primaryAccountHolder'.
I want the new compound index to allow users with same clubID to share an email but only one user in the same club can have the field primaryAccountHolder set to true. I have this index working locally but the updating on our existing data set is unsuccessful.

I believe this is because we have existing entries in our DB that won't allow this index to be updated. So my question is: 
how can I achieve updating a compound index that maintains uniqueness on an existing data set?
Below are the indexes I have created using Mongoose / Typescript. These work locally but not on our existing db.

Old Index:

UserSchema.index({ email: 1, clubID: 1 }, { unique: true })

// Won't allow a user of the same club to have the same email. This is the index on our DB.

New Index:

UserSchema.index({ email: 1, clubID: 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { email: { $exists: true }, primaryAccountHolder: { $eq: true } } })

// Will allow users to share an email but only one of them can have the primary account holder field set to true.

The new index uses a partial filter expression. This is the part that isn't created on the existing data set.

Thanks for the help!

Sam Gruse

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to drop and recreate the index:

```
UserSchema.dropIndex({ email: 1, clubID: 1 })
```

And then recreate it:

```
UserSchema.createIndex(
    { email: 1, clubID: 1 }, 
    { unique: true, 
        partialFilterExpression: 
        { email: { $exists: true },primaryAccountHolder: { $eq: true } }}
)
```

from MongoDB Documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#modify-an-index

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB cannot update an existing index. You need to drop the current index and create the new one.

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#modify-an-index:

> To modify an existing index, you need to drop and recreate the index. The exception to this rule is TTL indexes, which can be modified via the collMod command in conjunction with the index collection flag.